# What are buttholes for?

Tags: soma

What gameplay purpose do the biomechanical buttholes serve in SOMA? Are they save points? Health rechargers?

Some of them need to be activated to progress the story but others appear to be optional; is there a bonus/negative to activating them all?

Comment: You should change the title to "What are buttholes for?"

Comment: @DJMcMayhem - Why do you say that?

Comment: Because it would be funny, and because Arqade is famous for [out-of-context titles.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2196/103633)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem - Ha ha - you make a good point. Still, I feel like the current title is better for Google search rankings so other confused players can find the answer.

Comment: well it's your question, so name it whatever you want. However, funny titles always get more views, and it will still be tagged with "soma". But it's up to you.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem - you've convinced me. The more eyes we get on this, the better the chances of getting a certain answer (although Adam is probably correct). Title changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29597/discussion-between-christopher-and-dj-mcmayhem).

Comment: How about "What can I do with my butthole?" :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're used to recharge your health. If you fall enough to acquire a limp when you walk around, using one of the WAU sphincters will restore your legs.

As far as anyone knows right now, using all of them doesn't do anything. There are currently people trying to find speedrunning paths and techniques, so something might come out of that eventually.

---

It's rumored that there might be an alternate ending involved with these WAU sphincters, but the problem with that is the game forces you to fist the first one you encounter. It's possible that *other than that first one*, getting through the game without them could trigger something.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable answer but I'm kind of surprised if that is all they do. There are so many of them scattered throughout the game and so few moments where damage is possible (without instant-death). Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: @Christopher I added a little more info on what they might be.